# MongoDB query export into file

Tags: mongodb, export

Can i export a query from a mongodb collection like below to a file e.g. .csv file?

```
db.users.distinct('username', { loc: { $exists: true  }  } )﻿
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. export json result:

```
mongo < query_code.js > result.txt
```

#### 2. convert json to csv:

```
check here: [https://json-csv.com/][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongo doesn't have native support to export csv file. You can create a query file(make appropriate changes according to your collection) like this

```
print("field1,field2,field3,field4");
db.users.distinct('username', { loc: { $exists: true  }  } ).forEach(function(obj){
  print("{obj.field1},{obj.field2},{obj.field3}, {obj.field4}");
});
```

save it as `foo.js` , then invoke

```
mongo your_db foo.js > report.csv
```

Comment: When I did this the second print() results in a literal {obj.field1},{obj.field2} in the file and not the value for those. If I removed the quotes and braces it does output the values but without a comma. The correct syntax is print(obj.field1+","+obj.field2);